# Links (relations) to REST resources in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, hypermedia, ngresource

I have a REST API, which returns User object, where its roles are specified via link to another object. So at `localhost/project/api/users/27/` is JSON object:

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "name": "John",
    "prijmeni": "Doe",
    "login": "johndoe",
    "nickname": null,
    "grade": 1.3,
    "roles": {
        "href": "http://localhost/project/api/users/1716/roles/"
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get roles in controller. My User service looks like this:

```
projectServices.factory('User', ['$resource', 'UserRoles',
    function($resource, UserRoles, Role) {
        var User = $resource('http://localhost/project/api/users/:id', {}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            }
        });
        return User;
    }
]);
```

and I tried to add (to that resource code block):

```
User.prototype.roles= function(){
   return UserRoles.get({id:42});
};
```

this one freezes browser when called in ngRepeat. So I tried

```
User.prototype.roles = UserRoles.get({id:42});
```

this works. Then I tried

```
User.prototype.roles = $resource(this.roles.href, {}, {
   'get': {
      method: 'GET',
      isArray: true
   }
});
```

says, that `roles` is undefined. I also tried to add `transformResponse` param to User service `GET` action, but that function was never called.

The second option works just perfectly fine - except, that I have to hardcode the user ID. Suitable solution would be with somehow getting the user ID for me (i tried `this.id`, but that didn't work).

Perfect solution would be creating resource from given `href`, but as I can't access `roles` in prototype, I don't know how.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
projectServices.factory('UserRoles', function(){
    return $resource('http://localhost/project/api/users/:id', {id: @id}, 
        {'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        })
}
```

Now you can call it with

```
UserRoles.get({id:42})  
// this makes the request :     http://localhost/project/api/users/42
```

The *@id* tells angular to use the *id* key from the parameter passed.